# Capped running sum in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a data base with 3 columns ID, date, amount

| ID | date | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 2 |
| 2 | 2020-01-03 | 5 |
| 3 | 2020-01-08 | 10 |
| 4 | 2020-01-12 | -9 |
| 5 | 2020-01-12 | 3 |

I would like to do a simple running sum that would cap at 10 and then restart just after so the column I'm looking for would be :

| ID | date | amount | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 2020-01-03 | 5 | 7 |
| 3 | 2020-01-08 | 10 | 10 |
| 4 | 2020-01-12 | -9 | 1 |
| 5 | 2020-01-12 | 3 | 4 |

Most answers already existing involve recursive queries which are not possible in Big Query so I'm open to any idea.

Comment: how many rows in your table?

Comment: I have 5.6 M rows

Comment: any chance you have something to partition by  - for example by day or month?

Comment: The table is already partitioned by date. Worst case Scenario I'll split the table into several small tables on the IDs

Comment: i meant partition to use in the logic of capping

Comment: No I don't really have any other way to split my tables other then the ID. (I have a lot of different IDs so it should be ok)

Comment: And what if the "10" is not there but is 11 or 12?  What do the results look like?

Comment: It would still be 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a javascript UDF could help. Since what you actually want is a way to calculate the running sum following a couple of rules (i.e. add every positive number and keep the maximum of sum or 10, however if the number is negative reset and subtract from the sum). This logic can be encapsulated in the UDF and applied on and array that aggregates all the amounts up until a given day.

I am not entirely sure how this would scale for your 5.6M rows dataset, but for the example above it calculates the desired capped running sum.

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION calculate_sum(arr ARRAY<INT64>)
RETURNS INT64
LANGUAGE js AS """
  var sum = 0;
  for (var element in arr) {
    if(+arr[element] >= 0) {
     sum += +arr[element];
     sum = Math.min(sum, 10);
    } else if (+arr[element] < 0) {
     sum += +arr[element]
    }
  }
  return sum;
""";

WITH temp AS (
  SELECT 1 id, DATE("2020-01-01") date ,  2 AS amount UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, DATE("2020-01-03"),  5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, DATE("2020-01-08"),  10 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, DATE("2020-01-12"),  -9 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, DATE("2020-01-12"),  3
),
base AS (
SELECT date, amount, 
ARRAY_AGG(amount) OVER(ORDER BY id, date) AS t
FROM temp)
SELECT date, amount, calculate_sum(t) capped_sum FROM base
```

Which will give

| Row | date | amount | capped_sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 2020-01-03 | 5 | 7 |
| 3 | 2020-01-08 | 10 | 10 |
| 4 | 2020-01-12 | -9 | 1 |
| 5 | 2020-01-12 | 3 | 4 |